# Handle exception generated in DLL in WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, exception

I am facing a problem related with exception handling in WCF service. please anyone can help me for this.

**My problem: -**

I have WCF service which I am developing for mobile application.  In my WCF service I have a class library project in which there is a Class A. In that class I have defined a method which is getting some value from appsetting block of webconfig file(for ex UserID).

If I forgot to define that setting in webconfig the exception is coming in try catch block of that method.(everything is fine at this step) But Ideally that exception should also go in the catch block of respective WCF service method from where i am calling that Class A method.

This thing is not happing in my case. I am providing below 
code for refrence

Code written in ClassA (Placed in class library project)

```
public static string Method()
{
    try
    {
        string strdata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserID"].ToString();
        return strdata;
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        throw e1;
    }
}
```

Code written in WCF service:-

```
try
{
   ClassA.Method();
}
catch (Exception e2)
{

}
```

In above code if I forgot to define UserID setting in webconfig file then exception should also go in the catch block of WCF service method but it is not occring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not showing up in the WCF code, but by using `throw e1` you are losing the stack trace of the error, and this is generally considered a bad thing.

To be honest, I think you're using try-catch blocks here for the wrong reason.  You could easily check the returned value to see if it's empty or null without all the try catch code.  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` returns a string - calling `.ToString()` on it is redudant (though if the item is not present you will get a null reference exception).

I would rewrite your code this way:

```
public static string Method() 
{

    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserID"];
}
```

And then in your WCF code:

```
string userID = ClassA.Method();

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userID))
{
    // Do something with the error here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will try this it's looking fine.